# Unable to move the hash sign the right side

Tags: c#, .net

I'm unable to move the hash sign to the right to get the below shape.
My below code is working not as expected but I need to get the below shape.

Please how do I do it?

```
                #
               ##
              ###
             ####
            #####
           ######
          #######
```

```cs
public class MyProgramTest
{
    public static void StaircaseChallenge(int n)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine(MySpace(i) + HashSign(i));
        }
    }

    public static string HashSign(int n)
    {
        string t = "";

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            t += "#";
        }
        return t;
    }

    public static string MySpace(int n)
    {
        string t = "/t";

        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            t += " ";
        }
        return t;
    }

}
```

Comment: Use [PadLeft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Do you mean hash or pound sign..? A dash is "-"

Comment: @CodeStranger. I need to get that shape with hash.

Comment: Try `MySpace(n-i+1)` instead of just i. And "/t" is weird. For a Tab it should be a backslash. But i don't see why a TAB should be needed.

Comment: Take a look here: [StaircaseChallenge](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XJmbHw)

Comment: Tip: String has a constructor accepting a character and an amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   public class MyProgramTest
   {
        public static void StaircaseChallenge(int n)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" ".PadLeft(n - i+1, ' ')+"#".PadLeft(i,'#'));
            }
   }
```

Or make few changes to your code:

```
public class MyProgramTest
   {
    public static void StaircaseChallenge(int n)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(MySpace(n - i + 1) + HashSign(i));
            }
        }

        public static string HashSign(int n)
        {
            string t = "";

            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                t += "#";
            }
            return t;
        }

        public static string MySpace(int n)
        {
            string t = string.Empty;

            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            {
                t += " ";
            }
            return t;
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change only few things in your code :

```
public class MyProgramTest
{    
    public static void StaircaseChallenge(int n)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine(MySpace(i, n) + HashSign(i));
        }
    }

    public static string HashSign(int n)
    {
        string t = "";

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            t += "#";
        }
        return t;
    }

    public static string MySpace(int m, int n)
    {
        string t = "";

        for (int i = 1; i <= n - m; i++)
        {
            t += " ";
        }
        return t;
    }
}
```

You have to pass more one variable is n (number of row) in MySpace() function for leave space. When you pass number of row in MySpace() function then it will leave (number of row - 1) space. So if you enter 5 then first time it will leave 4 space and then put "#" like wise.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add some explanation as well, not just code (What should be changed and why)

Answer (score 1):

A more memory efficient way would be using the StringBuilder class.

For this situation it's not critical, but nice to know.

```
    // define the amount of steps 
    int n=8;              
    // amount of leading whitespaces, for later usage
    int padding=0;
    // this one is the "working" memory, initialized by n + padding whitespaces
    StringBuilder currentLine=new StringBuilder(new string(' ',n+padding));
    // it counts down from the last index to the one indicated by padding
    for (int i = currentLine.Length-1; i >=padding; i--)
    {
        // replace the char at the current index with #; (here: always the index of the last whitespace)
        currentLine[i]='#';
        // display a copy of the current state on the console, 
        Console.WriteLine(currentLine.ToString());    
    }
```